# local pc batch that runs different variables based on Active Directory group / local group

Tags: batch-file, startup, group-policy

I have one device on a network that requires special configuration. Since users need normal group policy settings on all other devices I want to place a batch in startup that will run configuration files on one machine based on group membership in active directory without the modification of network group policy.

I found a bit of code and modified it slightly, however I keep getting errors System error 5 access denied and password errors on the local accounts for the pc

CODE:

```
@echo on
set i=0
set group=Network-Oper
set groupA=Network-Eng
set groupB=Network-Tech
set user=%username%
for /f %%f in ('"net user %user% /domain | findstr /i %group%"') do set /a i-%i%+1
for /f %%f in ('"net user %user% /domain | findstr /i %groupA%"') do set /a i-%i%+2
for /f %%f in ('"net user %user% /domain | findstr /i %groupB%"') do set /a i-%i%+5
for /f %%f in ('"net user %user% administrator"') do set /a i-%i%+5
for /f %%f in ('"net user %user% Operator"') do set /a i-%i%+1 REM- Local PC account
if %i% EQU (goto :operator)
else
if %1% GEQ 2 (goto :admin)

:nonmember
msg Restricted
goto :EOF

:operator
msg Operator
goto :EOF

:admin
msg Admin
goto :EOF
```

Comment: still results in :nonmember

Comment: was able to resolve for network accounts by changing the set value syntax to     do set /a i=%i%+# , however I am still unable to match local accounts     for /f %%f in ('"net user %user% administrator"') ...  is not checking the value match and results with i=0

Comment: Try removing all doublequotes from the commands, it's wrong syntax, should be `for /f %%f in ('net user %user% /domain | findstr /i %group%')`

Comment: Also, your `if` \ `else` syntax is completely wrong. In your first one, you say `if %i% EQU` and then you don't compare it to anything. After that, the closing `)` needs to be on the same line as `else`, as does the opening `(` for the next bit.

Comment: And you also have no `=` signs anywhere in your `set` statements whatsoever, so %i% isn't even getting set.

Comment: Missing the value    if %i% EQU was a type-o should have value of 1. I had changed do set /a i=%i%+# which had all calls to the domain work. unfortunately the local users account I cannot seem to set a value for. tried a few things with no luck. thank you for replies

Comment: @wOxxOm, removing the quotes only works if you also escape the pipe like `^|`.

Comment: You can't just append a `rem`-ark to other commands (as you did in your 5th `for`), you need to state `&` to concenate commands (like `echo Hello & echo World! & rem Comment`).